# Database Loading Panel Screen StaticText is Blurred Out when Shown

Tags: python, hide, wxwidgets, show

Database Loading Panel Screen StaticText is Blurred Out when Shown

Hello,

I have an odd issue with a loading screen. The problem is this: When I start with a main screen, then when you click on the 'next' button,
it goes to the database loading screen, when it is done, it prints on the screen that the Database Loading is complete.

The problem is that the loading screen text is blurred out for some reason. Also, something I discovered is that if you pop up a message dialog
box, the loading text is shown...

In this example, I am not actually loading into an actual database. Instead, I am just sleeping for seven seconds.

If you are confused as to what I am saying, just run the example, and you will see that the loading screen is all messed up...

Here is the code:

```
import wx
import time

class TextPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, label):

        self.__myParent = parent    
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, self.__myParent, size = (800, 800))        
        staticText = wx.StaticText(self, label = label)

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.__myParent = parent    
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, self.__myParent, size = (800, 800))
        nextButton = wx.Button(self, label = 'Next')
        nextButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.__onNext)

    def __onNext(self, event):

        self.__myParent.onNextScreen()

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):  

    def __init__(self):

        # Base contsructor.
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id = -1, title = 'Testing...', size = (800, 800))

        self.__myMainPanel = MainPanel(self)
        self.__myMainPanel.Show()

        self.__myDatabase = TextPanel(self, 'Loading Data...')
        self.__myDatabase.Hide()

        self.__myFinalPanel = TextPanel(self, 'Database Loading Complete!')
        self.__myFinalPanel.Hide()

    def onNextScreen(self):

        self.__myMainPanel.Hide()
        self.__myDatabase.Show()

        self.doDatabaseLoad()

        self.__myDatabase.Hide()
        self.__myFinalPanel.Show()

    def doDatabaseLoad(self):    

        time.sleep(7) # before, this method would load data into a database...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()

    print 'Exiting...'
```

Comment: what OS/toolkit? What version? What wxPython/python version?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.13 (64-bit) with wxPython 3.0.2.0

Comment: What OS? What version? What toolkit? What version?

Comment: I am running Windows 7 Professional SP1 x64. The toolkit is wx version 3.0.2.0

Comment: I just noticed that if you call SetLabel('label') on the static text object, the label becomes visible. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help,

I found an easy solution to this issue.
I first found out that wx.Panel.Update() gets called to repaint the screen when ever the event handler method returns. So, the loading panel seems to look like it needed to be repainted, as the static text box is all grayed out. I then just called self.__myDatabase.Update() after self.__myDatabase.Show().
Here is the new version of onNextScreen(self):

```
def onNextScreen(self):

    self.__myMainPanel.Hide()
    self.__myDatabase.Show()

    self.__myDatabase.Update() # Fixes the bug...

    self.doDatabaseLoad()

    self.__myDatabase.Hide()
    self.__myFinalPanel.Show()
```

Also, another way to fix it is to call SetLabel on the static text, but the above solution is better. It just seems that Update was not being called automatically, because it was in the middle of an event...